# What is the execution sequence of functions while rendering a form?

Tags: theming, forms

I have a form in my website with id: `sample_test_custom_form`. I have used hook_form_alter in a custom module  to alter this form. I also have a preprocess function (`mytheme_preprocess_sample_test_custom_form`) to do a little preprocessing.

However the alter function and the preprocess function are a little dependent on each other.

So I ask, what is the execution sequence of these function? Which of them is executed first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a diagram of the form build workflow in Drupal 7

[image: Drupal 7 form building process]

More info: https://drupal.org/node/165104

Comment: It is quite informative but doesn't say anything about the *preprocessing* unless preprocessing is a part of form building. Is it?

Comment: Preprocessing is part of the theme layer. It will happen after form_alter